# Can anyone help me with this Advanced Multivariable Calculus question?

Tags: calculus

Suppose each of A and B is a number sequence. If A has a sequential limit number P and B has a sequential limit number Q, then does AB have sequential limit number PQ? Explain your answer using English sentences.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? What have you tried?

Comment: Tell us what you have attempted so far in this question.

Comment: Why do you call this *multivariable* calculus?

Comment: This is standard theory. Get an undergraduate text on elementary analysis.

Comment: This is basically an Advanced Multivariable Calulus class. I don't know what my teacher has done so far. His way of teaching is really weird. His problems all are similar to this. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Regardless of what you seem convinced to be "advanced calculus", the theorem is true, and you'll find it, or others as such, in any introductory book to calculus / real analysis.

Comment: See for example, Theorem 3.3 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*

Comment: @user259242 Can you send me a link of the textbook pls?

Comment: @NhãVy Try doing a google search for 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis'